# Is it possible to import image file dynamically in Nuxt js with env?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

// env.development.js

```js
module.exports = {
  fileName: 'banner_dev.png'
}
```

// env.production.js

```js
module.exports = {
  fileName: 'banner_prod.png'
}
```

// index.vue

```html
<script>
import bannerSrc from '@/assets/img/' + process.env.fileName

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      banner: {
        src: bannerSrc,
      }
    }
  },
</script>
```

Hello, I'm new to Nuxt js.
I would like to import an image file dynamically with using env value when build it.
However, I get error at below.

```
import bannerSrc from '@/assets/img/' + process.env.fileName
```

Is it possible to import image file dynamically with using env file?
If possible is there work around for it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Follow these steps:

1 - define your var in a .env file:

```
IMAGE=lama
```

2 - Add the environment var in your nuxt.config.js file:

```js
{
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    image: process.env.IMAGE
  },
}
```

3 - Call it in a vue.js file:

```html
<img
  :src="require(`~/assets/images/${$config.image}.jpg`)"
  style="width: 250px; height: 200px"
/>
```

Here is a codesand box:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxtjs-load-image-dynamically-with-environment-variable-e3xgf

Have fun! :)